# Auto-load Ivy.elc failed to define swiper

Tags: ivy

I get the followingerror message:

> command-execute: Autoloading file /home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/ivy-20210506.2157/ivy.elc failed to define function
> swiper

after just having installed emacs 27.2 and having this init.el:

```
;General Configuration
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(tooltip-mode -1)
(set-fringe-mode 10) ;was macht das?

(menu-bar-mode -1)
;;Set up the visible bell
(setq visible-bell t)

(load-theme 'wombat)

;; Make ESC quit prompts
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") 'keyboard-escape-quit)

;; Initialize package sources
(require 'package)

(setq package-archives '(("melpa". "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                         ("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents)) 

;; Initialize use-package on non-Linux platforms
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(require 'use-package)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

(use-package command-log-mode)

(use-package ivy
  :diminish
  :bind (("C-s" . swiper)
         :map ivy-minibuffer-map
         ("TAB" . ivy-alt-done)
         ("C-l" . ivy-alt-done)
         ("C-j" . ivy-next-line)
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         :map ivy-switch-buffer-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-l" . ivy-done)
         ("C-d" . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)
         :map ivy-reverse-i-search-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-d" . ivy-reverse-i-search-kill))
  :config
  (ivy-mode 1))
```

I have only one ivy folder in my load path.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/90hiew/swiper_disappeared/

Depending on whether ivy got installed from ELPA or MELPA it might be included or not.

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/90hiew/swiper_disappeared/

adding:

> (use-package swiper
> :ensure t)

solved the issue.